# How to update in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I never worked in database.But I read sqlite databse and manage to create table and how to insert in the table.But I want to know now how to update in database.As,Id which I am using is autoincrement so,how to update using autoincrement Id.

Will anybody help me.As,I am learning things in android.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: This [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) really helped me with sqlite

Comment: Check this : [Update SQlite1](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) [Update SQlite2](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) [Update SQlite3](http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/sqlite-database-example/) [Update SQlite4](http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/) Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Function in your Database class:

```
public void updateData(String str1, String str2) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
    cvUpdate.put("KEY name or id here", str1);

    yourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY name or id here+ "='"
            + str1+ "'", null);

}
```

Comment: when you will call this function at that time updated query will be fired from that function and you will know that data will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Update example 
  // Updating single contact
     public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}
```

[Check this for More Details](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Comment: But In this the KEY_ID is not autoincrement I think.

Comment: but when I am writing getWritableDatabse(),It is giving me an error and saying to create an method for that.It is required to create a method for same?

Comment: check the link for more details

Answer (score 0):

```
sdb=openOrCreateDatabase("sample.db", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
ContentValues cv= new ContentValues();
cv.put("col1","string1");
cv.put("col2","string2");
sdb.update("table", cv, "col_name = ?", new String[] {"col_name_value"});
sdb.close();
```

here `col_name` is an auto increment column